# update python so that it point to new version

Tags: python, linux

Here I installed Python on Amazon Linux 2.
python 2.7.18 was available by default.
i installed 3.9.6 but python --version point to python 2

```
[root@AnsibleM Python-3.9.6]# python --version
Python 2.7.18
[root@AnsibleM Python-3.9.6]#  python3.9 --version
Python 3.9.6
[root@AnsibleM Python-3.9.6]# which python
/usr/bin/python
[root@AnsibleM Python-3.9.6]# which python3.9
/usr/local/bin/python3.9
[root@AnsibleM Python-3.9.6]#
```

Comment: You can use alias. See this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051575/python-3-as-default-python-command

Comment: you can just add an alias in you `~/.bashrc` ... or you can just make `/usr/bin/python` soft liink to `/usr/bin/python3` ... or the "right way" is probably to use `update-alternatives`

Answer (score 0):

Same as recommended by other users, you can add:

```bash
alias python='/usr/local/bin/python3.9'
```

to the shell's `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`.

Then `python --version` should point to the correct version